# auto_increment with varchar in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE WishList(
    idWishList VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) ,
    WishListName  VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NOT  NULL,
    id_User  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT  NULL
)
```

now how can i use auto_increment with varchar in oracle ??

Comment: What do you mean by auto_increment with varchar ? Something like A,B,C,...,Z,AA,...,ZZ,AAA,or what?

Comment: This article seems helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1212905.aspx/1 . Also, I don't think it's called auto_increment in Oracle.

Comment: You need to give us an example of what you mean.  Please post some data.

Comment: What do you mean by auto_increment with varchar ? Something like A,B,C,...,Z,AA,...,ZZ,AAA,or what?  Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger some_trig_name
before insert on WishList
for each row
begin
:new.idWishList := to_char(your_sequence.nextval);
end some_trig_name;
```

In the example I used a seq but you can put whatever you want

Comment: This will result in wholly numeric data being stored in the `varchar2` field. If the OP wants actual alphanumeric data, some sort of translation scheme will need to be implemented between the sequence and the field.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, Oracle doesn't have an auto_increment functionality. It has sequences and developers should add special function like getNextId() and use it in insert statements like

```
insert into table (id,...) values(getNextId() ,..)
```

So, you can implement you own function which returns new id for your field with your own algorithm.